# Enable each TextBox with each CheckBox inside a loop

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a input type text inside a foreach. I see, for example five checkbox with five textbox. But by default I wanna see textbox only when i have enable the checkbox.

What's wrong with my jQuery code?

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="show" name="changedescr" value="changedescr"/>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class="hidden" });
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".hidden").hide();

  $(".show").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
      $(".hidden").each(function () {
        $(this).show();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No need to iterate through hidden and show, just use `$('.show').click(function(){$('.hidden').show()});`

Comment: I need iterate too because i have a list of them

Comment: jQuery iterates automatically

Comment: So what is your issue currently??? You should show elements on checkboxes change event. You should provide rendered HTML client side

Comment: When I enable one CheckBox I see all the textbox, but I want to see only one per checkbox

Comment: @Anton yea, it's similar. But how can i recover each textbox id? I have list of checkbox and textbox and i wanna show one textbox by click one of checkbox

Comment: Every selector in Jquery will return an array - you dont need that each.. `$('.hidden').show()` will do the same as `$('.hidden').each(function() { $(this).show() });`

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli Could you show your whole html rendered?

Comment: Also, show us some HTML pls.

Comment: update your code and show us the complete code (with the iteration) so we can help you

Comment: The iteration is a server side code. It show a simple list of checkbox and textbox. for this operation (checkbox select) javascript need to know something of this?

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli we need to see your html of checkboxes and textboxes after it's rendered, otherwise the solution could be anything, like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/9F7Qj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to toggle the text boxes on checkbox check/uncheck:

try this:

```
$('.hidden').hide();
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').toggle();
})
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/K4dCz/

Comment: thx for using `.toggle()`, i think more expected behaviour even OP didn't say anything about re-hide element

Comment: yes, only showing the content once wasn't making sense, tks.

Comment: Just wondering, better approach would be to toggle class hidden, i think...  http://jsfiddle.net/K4dCz/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="show" name="changedescr" value="changedescr" />
<input type="text" class="txt" />

<input type="checkbox" class="show" name="changedescr" value="changedescr" />
<input type="text" class="txt" />

<input type="checkbox" class="show" name="changedescr" value="changedescr" />
<input type="text" class="txt" />
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(".txt").hide();

$(".show").change(function() {
      $(this).next('.txt').toggle();
})
```